# Function to evaluate identity between characters strings

Tags: r, similarity

I have two character vectors describing the same objects, which have been produced by two different annotation programs. I need to make sure that the annotation is the same, however the description is not necessarily worded in the same way. I believe i need to do most of the work manually but i wonder if there is an R function that can calculate, for example, how many words are equal between each value of the two vectors. Or perhaps generate some sort of identity score. In this way i can at least order by similarity score. Below a small example of the dataset:

```
Annotation <- data.frame(Annotation.A = c("PREDICTED: similar to endonuclease domain containing 1 Coiled-coil domain-containing protein 58", "G protein pathway suppressor 2", "adducin 3a"), Annotation.B = c("PREDICTED: endonuclease domain-containing 1 protein-like [Xiphophorus maculatus] coiled-coil domain-containing protein 58 [Salmo salar]", "PREDICTED: G protein pathway suppressor 2-like [Takifugu rubripes]", "PREDICTED: gamma-adducin-like isoform X7 [Maylandia zebra]" ))
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This defines a mismatch score between each of the two elements of each row of `Annotation` and applies it giving a score to each row:

```
a <- Annotation
ch <- replace(a, TRUE, lapply(a, sub, pat = " *$", replace = "")) # rm trailing spaces
w <- lapply(ch, strsplit, " ") # split into words

mismatch <- function(x, y)
  (length(setdiff(x, y)) + length(setdiff(y, x))) / length(intersect(x, y))

# calculate mismatch score for each row of Annotation
mismatches <- sapply(1:nrow(a), function(i) mismatch(w[[1]][[i]], w[[2]][[i]]))

cutoff <- 2 # might need to change this
ok <- mismatches < cutoff
```

Also try using just the numerator of `mismatch()` to see if that is a better measure.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have not created two character vectors, ... those are factor vectors. It's going to be much easier if you do work with characters:

```
 Annotation <- data.frame(Annotation.A = c("PREDICTED: similar to endonuclease domain containing 1 Coiled-coil domain-containing protein 58", "G protein pathway suppressor 2", "adducin 3a"), Annotation.B = c("PREDICTED: endonuclease domain-containing 1 protein-like [Xiphophorus maculatus] coiled-coil domain-containing protein 58 [Salmo salar]", "PREDICTED: G protein pathway suppressor 2-like [Takifugu rubripes]", "PREDICTED: gamma-adducin-like isoform X7 [Maylandia zebra]" ),
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You would of course want to strip the "PREDICTED: letters out because they are sometimes present and sometimes not an clearly are not part of the content.

```
ann2 <- Annotation
ann2 <- lapply(ann2, gsub, patt="PREDICTED:", repl="")
```

Next, you need to tell what will be compared to what. Are we supposed to be comparing row 1 to row 2 or column 1 to column 2? Or all pairings of items in column 1 with column 2. Also, the second column has genus/species content while the first column does not. I'm getting concerned as I write this that the level of domain-specifc thought you are offering about this problem is less sophisticated than I would expect from a practicing biologist. Is this a homework question that you are asking us to do for you?

To get rid of hte genus/species items one could use:

```
ann2[] <- lapply(ann2, gsub, patt="\\[.+\\]", repl="")
```

Likewise, one column uses "similar to" and another uses "-like" which appear synonymous and don't really add information but obscure any similarity measure:

```
 ann2[] <- lapply(ann2, gsub, patt="\\-like|similar to", repl="")
```

So after improving the "biological content density" with further examination of the original data and application of domain-specific knowledge you may have something suitable for application of the other solutions.

Comment: @ BondedDust - I thank you very much for your answer which adds very good points to the previous solutions. I think there is no need to be offensive though, the reason why i ask questions on SOF is to get how people like yourself reason to solve a problem, that is just because i am a novice R user, not because i am lazy and i want you guys to add 2+2 for me. My "biological" problem was to verify two different annotations for more than 40K genes and i was looking for the best way to do it. That's all. I dont see how you would think i am trying to get you to do my homework.

Comment: You took offense? At what? If it were a homework problem, then shouldn't you have told us? If you pose a technical question in a technical forum, you should include as much relevant domain-specific issues to get the best answers.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your sentence then. :-) 
Thanks anyway, i adapted your approach to my entire dataset, adding further functions to clean my annotations and create "biologically-rich" terms. Worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* that the `jw` method for `stringdist` in the `stringdist` package could help:

```
library(stringdist)

print(stringdist("RED", "blue", method="jw", p=0))
## [1] 1

print(stringdist("light blue", "blue", method="jw", p=0))
## [1] 0.55

print(stringdist(Annotation$Annotation.A, Annotation$Annotation.B, method="jw", p=0))
## [1] 0.3210554 0.2262626 0.3890166
```

Some of the other methods may also help you arrive at a score you can use to determine "closeness".